# Giving a class member a reference to another classes members

Tags: java, oop

On a scale of one to ten, how bad is the following from a perspective of safe programming practices?  And if you find it worse than a five, what would you do instead?

My goal below is to get the data in the List of Maps in B into A.  In this case, to me, it is ok if it is either a copy of the data or a reference to the original data.  I found the approach below fastest, but I have a queasy feeling about it.

```
public class A {
    private List<Map<String, String>> _list = null;
    public A(B b) {
        _list = b.getList();
    }
}

public class B {
    private List<Map<String, String>> _list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    public List<Map<String, String>> getList() { 
        // Put some data in _list just for the sake of this example...
        _list.add(new HashMap<String, String>());
        return _list; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Using '_' as a prefix for private variables is outdated. Use `this.list` to signify access to a member variable. Also using single letters for classnames and variables reduces readability. `SomeClass`and `OtherClass` work as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying problem is a bit more complex:

- From a security perspective, this is very, very bad.
- From a performance perspective, this is very, very good.
- From a testing perspective, it's good because there is nothing in the class that you can't easily reach from a test
- From an encapsulation perspective, it's bad since you expose the inner state of your class.
- From a coding safety perspective, it's bad because someone will eventually abuse this for some "neat" trick that will cause odd errors elsewhere and you will waste a lot of time to debug this.
- From an API perspective, it can be either: It's hard to imagine an API to be more simple but at the same time, it doesn't communicate your intent and things will break badly if you ever need to change the underlying data structure.

When designing software, you need to keep all of these points in the back of your mind. With time, you will get a feeling which kinds of errors you make and how to avoid them. Computers being as dump and slow as they are, there is never a perfect solution. You can just strive to make it as good as you can make it at the when you write it.

If you want to code defensively, you should always copy any data that you get or expose. Of course, if "data" is your whole data model, then you simply can't copy everything each time you call a method.

Solutions to this deadlock:

- Use immutables as often as you can. Immutables and value objects are created and never change after that. These are always safe and the performance is OK unless the creation is very expensive. Lazy creation would help here but that is usually its own can of worms. Guava offers a comprehensive set of collections which can't be changed after creation.

  Don't rely too much on `Collections.unmodifiable*` because the backing collection can still change.
- Use copy-on-write data structures. The problem above would go away if the underlying list would clone itself as soon as A or B start to change it. That would give each its own copy effectively isolation them from each other. Unfortunately, Java doesn't have support for these built in.

Comment: Thanks.  I will investigate immutable collections.  I was not aware such a thing existed.  QUESTION:  Would creating (and thus returning) a copy of the data in B's getList() be an adequately "defensive" solution?

Comment: The usual solution is to let getList() either return an immutable list  or a new one (so the caller can use it any way it likes): just `return new ArrayList<...>(_list);`

Answer (score 2):

> In this case, to me, it is ok if it is either a copy of the data or a reference to the original data.

That is the sticking point.

Passing the object instance around is the fastest, but allows the caller to change it, and also makes later changes visible (there is no snapshot).

Usually, that is not a problem, since the caller is not malicious (but you may want to protect against coding errors).

If you do not want the caller to make changes, you could wrap it into an [immutable wrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29).

If you need a snapshot, you can clone the list.

Either way, this will only snapshot/protect the list itself, not its individual elements. If those are mutable, the same reasoning applies again.

Comment: Thanks.  So, if I am ok with the caller changing the data, and thus affecting the contents of B as well, my approach would not be horrible?  Less than a six on the badness scale?

Comment: Having a getter in a class that directly returns a member object (even if not mutable) is a totally common and accepted pattern. Do decide if it is "horrible", we'd need more context. In itself, there is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you will have too choose between efficiency and encapsulation. By directly accessing a member of the class it will have its state changed. That might be unexpected and lead to nasty surprises. I would also say that it increases the coupling between the two classes.

An alternative is to let the information expert principle decide and leave the job to the class that have the information. You will have to judge if the work that was suppose to be done with class A really is the responsibility of class B.

But really, speed and clean code can be conflicting interests. Some times you just have to play dirty to get it quick enough.

Answer (score 1):

All you're creating is a reference to B._list. So 10 if you wanted to copy the items. 
You could iterate over all b._list items and add them to the A._list manually:

```
public A(B b) {
    _list = new List<Map<String, String>> ();
    for (Map<String,String> map : b.getList()) {
        Map<String,String> newMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        while(map.keySet().iterator().hasNext()) {
            String key = map.keySet().iterator().next();
            newMap.put(key,map.get(key));
        }
        _list.add(newMap);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will that give me copies of the contents of the elements (the Maps) in B's List?

Comment: So.. This should do the copy trick, hope my editing didn't confuse you too much